# pcsc-lite and ccid on Android

Tags: android, linux, pcsc

Does anyone have experience porting pcsc-lite/ccid to Android? I don't need to access smart cards/readers from the application layer, just from the shell. So, as long as I can get the pcscd daemon to run, that's fine.

Do I have to also port libusb/libhal to Android since pcsc-lite requires either?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been done and it works, however not sure what Android version the current patch supports. Check the SEEK site and their mailing list for more information: https://seek-for-android.github.io/.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm not wrong, seek for android seems to be for the application layer. Does it also do the lower native level in C?

Comment: The application layer has to talk to the hardware somehow :) Yes, there is code in C, but you don't need the full thing if you only want PCSC-lite. Are you trying to talk to an external reader connected via USB? There is also a package that enables this without PCSC-lite on supported devices.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to talk to an external CCID compliant USB reader with a USB-OTG converter.